# Rcrawler - How to crawl account/password protected sites?

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler, web-mining, rcrawler

I am trying to crawl and scrape a website's tables. I have an account with the website, and I found out that Rcrawl could help me with getting parts of the table based on specific keywords, etc. The problem is that on the GitHub page there is no mentioning of how to crawl a site with account/password protection.

An example for signing in would be below:

```
login <- list(username="username", password="password",)
```

Do you have any idea if Rcrawler has this functionality? For example something like:

```
Rcrawler(Website = "http://www.glofile.com" +
list (username = "username", password = "password" + no_cores = 4, no_conn = 4, ExtractCSSPat = c(".entry-title",".entry-content"), PatternsNames = c("Title","Content"))
```

I'm confident my code above is wrong, but I hope it gives you an idea of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

To **crawl or scrape password-protected websites** in R, more precisely **HTML-based Authenticatio**n, you need to use web driver to stimulate a login session, Fortunately, this is possible since **Rcrawler v0.1.9**, which implement **phantomjs** web driver ( a browser but without graphics interface).

In the following example will try to log in a blog website

```
 library(Rcrawler)
```

Dowload and install web driver

```
install_browser()
```

Run the browser session

```
br<- run_browser()
```

If you get an error than disable your antivirus or allow the program in your system setting

Run an automated login action and return a logged-in session if successful

```
 br<-LoginSession(Browser = br, LoginURL = 'http://glofile.com/wp-login.php'
                 LoginCredentials = c('demo','rc@pass@r'),
                 cssLoginFields =c('#user_login', '#user_pass'),
                cssLoginButton ='#wp-submit' )
```

Finally, if you know already the private pages you want to scrape/download use

```
DATA <- ContentScraper(... , browser =br)
```

Or, simply crawl/scrape/download all pages

```
Rcrawler(Website = "http://glofile.com/",no_cores = 1 ,no_conn = 1,LoggedSession = br ,...)
```

Don't use multiple parallel no_cores/no_conn as many websites reject multiple sessions by one user.
Stay legit and honor robots.txt by setting  Obeyrobots = TRUE

You access the browser functions, like :

```
 br$session$getUrl()
 br$session$getTitle()
 br$session$takeScreenshot(file = "image.png")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer....It looks like an interesting idea to use the Phantomjs. I am no longer working on the project that needed a creative Rcrawler solution but I am confident that the challenge with phantomjs would have been their network security. But if it allows it to run it might be an amazing solution.